# Push Notification getting error (Using Adhoc Certificate) in php side

Tags: php, ssl

I am receiving the error while using push notification (adhoc certificate) from php side. like this.

> `stream_socket_client() [function.stream-socket-client]: unable to connect to ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195 (php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: hostname nor servname provided, or not known) in /usr/local/www/apache24/data/appmantras/community/apple/push.php on line 19`

I have one doubt that where I need to create *.csr file i.e from my development mac system or server system. (Now I have created from my mac system only.)

Comment: Looks like your server prevents outbound connections (maybe a firewall?) or the DNS server on your server can't find `gateway.push.apple.com`. To confirm, open up an ssh session and call `host gateway.push.apple.com`. If that returns a couple of IPs, try pinging: `ping gateway.push.apple.com`.

Comment: R u sure this is the issue with the server.? can u clear my doubt about csr file as mentioned above. Thanks for ur comments. i will check.

Comment: Sidenote: You're using `ssl://` (that is SSLv2 pre PHP 5.6) which is insecure, just as `sslv3://` (SSLv3) is. You should switch to TLS instead by using `tls://gateway.push.apple.com:2195/...`.

Comment: RJV Kumar, you can be sure by checking with `host`/`ping` as I said in my first comment.

Comment: @Bjorn,  i have one doubt where i need to create .pem file. i.e from my mac sysytem or server system.

Comment: The error you've shared has nothing to do with certificates. It just says that it cannot resolve the domain name into an ip address. About certificates: you should create your CSR (certificate signing request) on the computer you would like to use the certificate on. Upload the CSR to Apple, and they will send you a `.pem`. You install the certificate on the computer you generated the CSR on. So you have a cert for both your dev machine and server.

Comment: @Bjorn As you said, this is the issue from server side. They solved the issue now. Its working fine.